# LINQ Compund FROM cluase for separate objects

Tags: c#, linq, valuetuple

There is a more or less recent (Jan 2020) video on YouTube explaining how to use a compound `where` clause in LINQ. In this example, the `where` is used twice, but for objects that are not related. When I try this in Visual Studio 2017 (in a Program.cs file) I get an error:

```
Error: Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
```

*Previously I was getting an error about the `foreach` clause.*

The example is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUsnDXYRADA&t=263s , and is as follows:
int[] numbersA = {0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9};
int[] numbersB = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};

```
var pairs = from a in numbersA
            from b in numbersB
            where a < b
            select (a, b);

Console.WriteLine("Pairs where a < b:");
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.a} is less than {pair.b}");
}
```

*I have VS Professional 2017, with ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 5.2.6, Core Razor 15.8, C# Tools 2.10*
*LINQ works in the system, but this query does not.*

Comment: The sample code you've provided compiles and runs for me. I must be missing something. Could you restate the question in different words?

Comment: @NateW please check my answer. the code has no problem, it is the version of the framework that is the issue here.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, yes. It ended up being the missing Tuple datatype.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to `Linq`, you are returning a `Tuple` type which your current version of Framework does not support it. `Tuple`s are supported in .Net Framework 4.7+. If you upgrade your project to use a higher framework version (4.7+), the code will work.

[More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0)